# General Physics Short question

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Does any one know where this formula come from ?

$\alpha (t) = -\omega^2\ \Theta(t)$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the formula relating the [angular acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_acceleration) $\alpha$ and the angular displacement $\theta$. The $\omega$ is the angular frequency and this equation is the same as the [simple harmonic oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator). You can think of a spinning wheel rotating back and fro forever.